# DOM traversing doesn't work with prev()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My DOM look like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiMl0.png

and my Jquery :

```
$('.content').each(function(){
    $(this).find('img').prev().removeAttr('height width style');
});
```

How come the div still have style attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent) or [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) like ,

```
$('.content').each(function(){
     $(this).find('img').closest('div').removeAttr('height width style');
});
```

If you have multiple images then you can use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next) from h3 element like,

```
$('.content').each(function(){
     $(this).find('h3').next('div').removeAttr('height width style');
});
```

And if you want only the images having parent div then you can try it like,

```
$('.content > div').each(function(){
     $(this).find('img').closest('div').removeAttr('height width style');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use,

```
$('.content').each(function(){
     $(this).find('img').parent().closest('div').removeAttr('height width style');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use shorter code then you can use this:

```
$('.content div[style]:has(img)').removeAttr('style');
```

This will work because your `div` which is child of `.content` div, it doesn't have the `width, height` attributes other than `style`.

#### [Working Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu4tewsf/)

#### [Non-working Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu4tewsf/1/)

The non-working demo: The selector does not have the attributes on it so it is not getting affected.